# In React, Is it possible to get access to Redux action creators from inside a utility function?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a form input validation function that just returns an empty errors object or a populated errors object.

```
const validate = function validateSomeInput({ field1, field2 }) {
  const errors = {}
  // some logic
  return errors
}

export default validate
```

Is there a way to hook an action creator into this function?

This is what I am trying to achieve:

```
const validate = function validateSomeInput({ field1, field2 }) {
  const errors = {}
  // some logic
  props.onErrorEvent('do something')
  return errors
}

export default connect(null, { onErrorEvent })(validate)
```

My issue is that since **it's not a class**, I don't have access to `this.props`, and I have never tried to make a container before that **doesn't render any JSX**.

I also can't create a callback into the parent because the validate function is controlled by `Redux-Form`.

It's used like this in the parent container:

```
export default compose(
  connect(mapStateToProps, {
    onErrorEvent,      // this is the action creator I want to access from validate
    onLoginSuccess,
  }),
  graphql(LOGIN_MUTATION),
  reduxForm({
    validate,           // how do I get an action creator into this function?
    form: 'LoginForm',
  }),
)(LoginForm)
```

> Is it possible to wire an action creator into a utility function that doesn't render JSX and can't callback to parent?

I'd also like to know if this is bordering into any kind of horrendous anti-pattern territory because I can't find any information about allowing random utility functions to call action creators.

I didn't see a solution with `bindActionCreators`, but maybe I just didn't see how it relates to this scenario.

Is there a way I can create a HOC in this scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `validate` function receives a second argument, which are the component props.  This makes it trivial to pass in the dispatch-bound action creators.  See the [docs](https://redux-form.com/6.6.1/docs/api/reduxform.md/) for details, but your code example should work if you examine the 2nd argument:

```
function validate({ field1, field2 }, {onErrorEvent}) {
  // ...
}

export default compose(
  connect(mapStateToProps, {
    onErrorEvent,      // this is the action creator I want to access from validate
    onLoginSuccess,
  }),
  graphql(LOGIN_MUTATION),
  reduxForm({
    validate,           // how do I get an action creator into this function?
    form: 'LoginForm',
  }),
)(LoginForm)
```

If you want to insulate the validation function from the action, then use this pattern:

```
function sendOnError(validate, fields, props) {
  const result = validate(fields, props);
  if (!_.isEmpty(result)) {
    props.onErrorAction(...);
  }
  return result;
}

const myValidator = ({field1, field2}) => ...;

export default compose(
  connect(mapStateToProps, {
    onErrorEvent,      // this is the action creator I want to access from validate
    onLoginSuccess,
  }),
  graphql(LOGIN_MUTATION),
  reduxForm({
    validate: sendOnError.bind(null, myValidator),
    form: 'LoginForm',
  }),
)(LoginForm)
```

Comment: Amazing. This is what I was looking for. I've never actually tested multiple params like this on "random functions". Thanks, let me work with this new data. React is full of secrets.

Answer (score 4):

You can access the redux store directly yes.

**Step 1: Export the store**

In the file where you initially configure your store, make sure you export it as well so you can have a reference to it from anywhere inside your app:

```
import {createStore} from 'redux'

const store = createStore([... your config]);

export default store;
```

**Step 2: Use it anywhere in your code**

```
import {reduxStore} from './store'; // your previous created file

const yourEntireReduxState = reduxStore.getState();
// use it whichever way you want here
```

**Step 3: Dispatch actions**

```
import {reduxStore} from './store'; // your previous created file

store.dispatch({type: 'YOUR_ACTION', payload: {...}});
```

Comment: Is this legitimate though? Do I need to bring the entire store in and manually call `store.dispatch()` ?

Comment: This is exactly what `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` do. These two functions are just an 'easy to use with react' wrapper around what I have described in my solution

Comment: Is there a way to use `connect()` and `import { onErrorEvent } from './some_actions'` and make it available in this function? That's really what I'm trying to do. I want to be able to call `onErrorEvent()` from inside the validate function. The validate function should not be aware that a store exists.

Comment: Upon further research, it seems like it's possibly required to get store in, because you need to pull dispatch off of it. That would allow me to use https://redux.js.org/docs/api/bindActionCreators.html

Answer (score 1):

[Redux Thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) would be a good way to do this. It's a middleware that allows you to write action creators that return functions, gives you access to the store, and allows you to dispatch other actions from action creators.

```js
import { onErrorEvent } from '../wherever';

const validate = function validateSomeInput({ field1, field2 }) {
  return function(dispatch, getState) {
    const errors = {}
    // some logic
    dispatch(onErrorEvent('do something'))
    return errors
  }
}
```

Comment: I am using redux-thunk already. Will your code work as is? That would be amazing.